# Extracting a number of a string of varying lengths

Tags: r, string, strsplit

Pretend I have a vector:

```
testVector <- c("I have 10 cars", "6 cars", "You have 4 cars", "15 cars")
```

Is there a way to go about parsing this vector, so I can store just the numerical values:

```
10, 6, 4, 15
```

If the problem were just "15 cars" and "6 cars", I know how to parse that, but I'm having difficulty with the strings that have text in front too!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` with pattern `\\d+` which means to match one or more numbers.  It can be otherwise written as `[0-9]+`.

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(testVector, "\\d+"))
#[1] 10  6  4 15
```

If there are multiple numbers in a string, we use `str_extract_all` which wil1 return a `list` output.

---

This can be also done with `base R` (no external packages used)

```
as.numeric(regmatches(testVector, regexpr("\\d+", testVector)))
#[1] 10  6  4 15
```

Or using `gsub` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", testVector))
#[1] 10  6  4 15
```

---

BTW, some functions are just using the `gsub`, from `extract_numeric`

```
function (x) 
 {
   as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "", as.character(x)))
 }
```

So, if we need a function, we can create one (without using any external packages)

```
ext_num <- function(x) {
             as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x))
         }
ext_num(testVector)
#[1] 10  6  4 15
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you help describe to me what "\\d+" means?

Comment: @Sheila Updated the post

Comment: regex https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 5):

For this particular common task, there's a nice helper function in `tidyr` called `extract_numeric`:

```
library(tidyr)

extract_numeric(testVector)
## [1] 10  6  4 15
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also come in handy .

```
testVector <- gsub("[:A-z:]","",testVector)
testVector <- gsub(" ","",testVector)

> testVector
[1] "10" "6"  "4"  "15"
```