# repeat row data with categorical variable a varying number of times

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
DATE    SURVEY  SPECIES COUNT
07/12/16    13  Paka    1
07/12/16    14  Paka    1
07/12/16    15  Grouper 2
07/12/16    16  Grouper 3
07/12/16    18  Grouper 1
07/12/16    20  Lehi    3
```

Where 'Count' is the number of individuals observed for each given survey. I'd like to reshape the data so that there is a single row (record) for each individual: e.g.:

```
DATE    SURVEY  SPECIES
07/12/16    13  Paka
07/12/16    14  Paka
07/12/16    15  Grouper
07/12/16    15  Grouper
07/12/16    16  Grouper
07/12/16    16  Grouper
07/12/16    16  Grouper
07/12/16    18  Grouper
07/12/16    20  Lehi
07/12/16    20  Lehi
07/12/16    20  Lehi
```

With the data for each survey replicated as many times as needed. I considered using the melt() or summarise() functions but am stuck because the COUNT variable ranges anywhere from 1 - 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you original data frame is `dat`, You can do the following to get your desired data frame `new_dat`:

```
new_dat <- dat[rep.int(1:nrow(dat), dat$COUNT), -4]
rownames(new_dat) <- 1:nrow(new_dat)
```

The key is the row indexing vector `rep.int(1:nrow(dat), dat$COUNT)`, while the `-4` only signals dropping the 4th column, i.e., column `COUNT`.

---

**Test**

```
x <- "DATE    SURVEY  SPECIES COUNT
      07/12/16    13  Paka    1
      07/12/16    14  Paka    1
      07/12/16    15  Grouper 2
      07/12/16    16  Grouper 3
      07/12/16    18  Grouper 1
      07/12/16    20  Lehi    3"

dat <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE)

#DATE   SURVEY  SPECIES COUNT
#07/12/16   13  Paka    1
#07/12/16   14  Paka    1
#07/12/16   15  Grouper 2
#07/12/16   16  Grouper 3
#07/12/16   18  Grouper 1
#07/12/16   20  Lehi    3

new_dat <- dat[rep.int(1:nrow(dat), dat$COUNT), -4]
rownames(new_dat) <- 1:nrow(new_dat)

#        DATE SURVEY SPECIES
#1   07/12/16     13    Paka
#2   07/12/16     14    Paka
#3   07/12/16     15 Grouper
#4   07/12/16     15 Grouper
#5   07/12/16     16 Grouper
#6   07/12/16     16 Grouper
#7   07/12/16     16 Grouper
#8   07/12/16     18 Grouper
#9   07/12/16     20    Lehi
#10  07/12/16     20    Lehi
#11  07/12/16     20    Lehi
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `expandRows`

```
library(splitstackshape)
`row.names<-`(expandRows(df1, "COUNT"), NULL)
#      DATE SURVEY SPECIES
#1  07/12/16     13    Paka
#2  07/12/16     14    Paka
#3  07/12/16     15 Grouper
#4  07/12/16     15 Grouper
#5  07/12/16     16 Grouper
#6  07/12/16     16 Grouper
#7  07/12/16     16 Grouper
#8  07/12/16     18 Grouper
#9  07/12/16     20    Lehi
#10 07/12/16     20    Lehi
#11 07/12/16     20    Lehi
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  The assignment is to make it one-line making, but basically the `expandRows` is just a wrapper which does the same thing as in your code.  However, people are posting wrappers as a unique solution and getting more points.  Example in point is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711057/extracting-a-number-of-a-string-of-varying-lengths/38711116#38711116)